# REST request with specific content type

Tags: rest, windows-phone-7, spring.net

I'm successfully using Spring.net Rest on WP7 since [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334788/windows-phone-7-webrequest-caching/).

My REST service requires a specific content type. I tried to used another request interceptor but XElementHttpMessageConverter overrides the content type.

```
public MyClient(string baseAddress)
{
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(baseAddress);
    //restTemplate.RequestInterceptors.Add(new NoCacheRequestInterceptor());
    restTemplate.MessageConverters.Add(new XElementHttpMessageConverter());
}

public MyObject GetMyObject(int id)
{
    XElement element = restTemplate.GetForObject<XElement>("path/{id}", id);
    //..
    return myObject;
}

// more methods
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way here to do that is to configure your converter with the "SupportedMediaTypes" property :

```
public MyClient(string baseAddress)
{
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(baseAddress);
    //restTemplate.RequestInterceptors.Add(new NoCacheRequestInterceptor());

    XElementHttpMessageConverter linqXmlConverter = new XElementHttpMessageConverter ();
    linqXmlConverter.SupportedMediaTypes = new MediaType[] { MediaType.Parse("type/subtype") };
    restTemplate.MessageConverters.Add(linqXmlConverter );
}
```

Btw, you could do that with an interceptor too but not with the "IClientHttpRequestFactoryInterceptor" that intercepts request creation.
You should use instead "IClientHttpRequestBeforeInterceptor" that intercepts request execution.