# Sync data between webclient windows phone and webservice

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm using a webclient on a windows phone 8 app, i have to sync some data with the webservice each minutes (or by pressing a button). I put my webclient in a private data of my object :

```
private WebClient client_summary;
```

At the launch of the app the client connects to the webservice :

```
client_summary = new WebClient();
client_summary.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("random url" + info_conf.id));
client_sommaire.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadSummaryConf);
```

I recovered well data, but each time i want to re sync my webclient, data remain the same :(

```
DispatcherTimer TradeThread = new DispatcherTimer();
TradeThread.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
TradeThread.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
TradeThread.Start();

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        pivotMainList.Items.Clear();           

        summary.Children.Clear();
        client_summary.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("url" + info_conf.id));


    }
private void client_DownloadSummaryConf(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result); 
    }
```

e.Result remain the same, whereas if I restart my app the data sync correctly
I don't understand why the sync didn't work ... 
Please tell me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a caching issue - the **Webclient** class (and the **HttpClient** class if you chose to use that instead) caches server responses. The standard workaround is to append something that varies to your querystring.

For examples see:

- [How do you disable caching with WebClient and Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173052/how-do-you-disable-caching-with-webclient-and-windows-phone-7)
- [Windows Phone 7 WebRequest caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334788/windows-phone-7-webrequest-caching)